# Proper IntelliSense and type checking for deep object keys / paths as function arguments without triggering recursive type limiters

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Suppose I have a dictionary like the following:

```
const obj = {
  something: 123,
  otherThing: "asd",
  nested: {
    nestedSomething: 456,
    nestedOther: "fgh",
    deepNested: {
      deepNested1: "hello",
      deepNested2: 42,
      deepNestedArr: ["a", "b", "c"],
    },
  },
};
```

and I want to have a function `access` that can be used to access the values of this dictionary like this:

```
access(obj, "something") //should return number
access(obj, "nested", "nestedOther") //should return string
access(obj, "nested", "deepNested", "deepNestedArr") //should return string[]
//and even:
access(obj, "nested", "deepNested", "deepNestedArr", 0) //should return string
```

For this, I first need a utility type that can get an object type and output a union of all possible paths to leaves in this object. I implement it like this:

```
type AllPaths<Obj extends object, Key = keyof Obj> = Key extends keyof Obj
  ? Readonly<Obj[Key]> extends Readonly<Array<any>>
    ? [Key] | [Key, number]
    : Obj[Key] extends object
      ? [Key] | [Key, ...AllPaths<Obj[Key]>]
      : [Key]
  : never;
```

And when given a concrete type as an argument, it works:

```
type Test = AllPaths<typeof obj>; 
//["something"] | ["otherThing"] | ["nested"] | ["nested", "nestedSomething"] | ["nested", "nestedOther"] | ["nested", "deepNested"] | ["nested", "deepNested", "deepNested1"] | [...] | [...] | [...]
```

Then I need an utility type that takes an object type and the path we generated earlier, indexes into the object and returns the resulting type. I implement it like this:

```
type GetTypeFromPath<Obj extends object, Path extends PropertyKey[]> = Path extends [
  infer Head,
  ...infer Tail extends PropertyKey[]
]
  ? Head extends keyof Obj
    ? Obj[Head] extends object
      ? GetTypeFromPath<Obj[Head], Tail>
      : Obj[Head]
    : never
  : Obj;
```

...which also works when given concrete arguments.

```
type Test2 = GetTypeFromPath<typeof obj, ["nested", "deepNested", "deepNested2"]> //number
```

These utilities work in isolation when given concrete types, and they are performant.

Now if I try to use them in a function with generic type arguments though, tsserver hangs a bit, then gives "Type instantiation is excessively deep.." or "Excessive stack depth comparing types..." errors depending on how I set up the generics. No matter what I do, I am not able to avoid triggering the limiters. Is there a sane way to achieve this?

```
declare function access<
  Obj extends object,
  //providing the default only does not work without extends for some reason
  Paths extends AllPaths<Obj> = AllPaths<Obj>,
  Ret = GetTypeFromPath<Obj, Paths>
>(
  obj: Obj,
  ...path: Paths
): Ret;

const res = access(obj, "nested", "deepNested");
```

Above, the generic type Ret can't be computed because it is excessively deep.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGEQFsBTKACwEswBzALhgEYAmAZgBps5TCAnAFXKtoAiAIYQAJoLY4whaITG0sOabKjyAygWL8aMACwBWAGxTlMuWIDynLkIBmlEpPY4xhQgAcAcqvmKXym6ePhZ0QiSEADaRIM7Kge7evmIMtHoMpvFBSRYAgly2MADaIpIwgvBlgsCCALqZMAC+ps2YjQDcmJhQAJ4ehDC50QAKwqQQADyWSDCEAB5qYGIQcEiEwFAsMADShD2oMADWeyB2MNOIAHwHu-vzi8tHJ2cX7AD8MABKhMJi4JE9KZIIq3WrXe6EJYrb6-f6A-JcYSA4RgHqXS4BD4gva1GAAH2Kty2YAArvh4NxagFaBdsT1cRCoatEOsoJjCTj8RyelsAHT8oaRUbjIGIOlgqnxWji9i0GQAN24nW6fQGPFUB0FwpIk16-VOzMuyr1AwA4sQeKqAGJcAja0WzBaQx4IFkbLbax0PFbDW39Li9W5FMEHT2Mx5FdgUOzcGAACR+YlM-N50djPGEZEiXudPr93EDe2DmElMA+Cd+OaZxx6Bte8Q+tIrYgZTqZrtZARwH3NUEt-RtdrGJFFRWb9RgGazGPiOBpwPH1JgCu4svOSGNqsnqgYB17-cIg-w9pNBtdWxK5jUEi2gmyIWvVXvyQYdQxmDcwEiwi4AzsJLADYyHAGBhGAYBZEmdgLirF01nddgAHpEI8W15TIMQKEoGBOBgNw7GEElIlgOE8JAWRlxAWAAHcQC4Q4YGoshSBAElYHDFY7Do3AtBgX9RHAdhtRWDjBhGYdJgua40C1CTRUuUxvlgNB92tW1j2HUUPQkjFLgACnYV150QZN+Q8YdaGEzAAEpaCU5VQEgWBfxWNAwIgiAID089yiveQn0SB9-OszogA)

This all is for an API boundary, so having errors at the `access` call site if wrong path to the object keys is entered and having proper IntelliSense while entering the keys for the function is enough for my purposes.

Comment: • This is close to a duplicate of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/63650858/2887218). If you don't think so, please [edit] to distinguish them clearly. •If you do that, then does [this approach](//tsplay.dev/W4aKXw) meet your needs? Note that you don't necessarily need "validate path" stuff if you just want errors, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/Na5VEN). Right now you've only shown use cases you want to support but not anything about IntelliSense or use cases you want to prohibit.  Anyway if either of those meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you @jcalz I think the question can be considered a duplicate (I had not encountered that question before though). The approach in there, while beautiful in a grotesque sense, is not the "sane" way I am looking for (limiters, magic numbers..). The solution in the playground ticks almost all boxes but I don't get right intellisense while typing in parameters (but checking works!). I'd like to have only keys under "nested" to be suggested when "nested" is the second parameter etc. Would love to hear more about "extends never ? never : unknown" trick (which defers resolution maybe?) though.

Comment: You *don't* get the proper IntelliSense with [this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4aKXw)? I'm surprised, because I do get what I consider proper intellisense from that. Note that the question doesn't talk about IntelliSense so it's kind of out of scope unless you [edit]. The trick you're talking about is from the version I explicitly said "if you just want errors" for. How do you want to proceed?

Comment: oops, my bad. don't know what went wrong earlier but playground would show me random keys from random depths as suggestions earlier, but now IntelliSense seems to work just fine! I have edited the title and added some content to better reflect my intent for asking the question. The playground version meets my needs perfectly.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of deeply recursive and nested types are always going to have bizarre edge cases, and it's inevitable that some uses of them will trigger circularity or depth limit warnings.  So while I will present something that works how I think you want it for this example, I can't guarantee it will behave that way for all use cases.

---

Let's write the function like this

```
declare function access<T, const KS extends PropertyKey[]>(
  obj: T, ...ks: ValidPathMap<T, KS>): DeepIdx<T, KS>
```

where we have to define `DeepIdx<T, KS>` to be the nested property type of the type `T` at the path represented by `KS`, and `ValidPathMap<T, KS>` to be something that examines `T` and `KS` and makes sure `KS` is a valid path of `T`. If it is valid, then `ValidPathMap<T, KS>` should evaluate to `KS`. If it is invalid, it should evaluate to something valid which is "close" to `KS` in the sense that the error message will let the user know what's wrong.  Ideally `ValidPathMap<T, KS>` will also let users know the next valid key if `KS` is just a partial path.

---

The easy part is `DeepIdx<T, KS>`:

```
type DeepIdx<T, KS extends PropertyKey[]> =
  KS extends [infer K0 extends keyof T, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
  DeepIdx<T[K0], KR> : T;
```

Here we don't really care if `KS` is a valid path. If `KS` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) that starts with a valid key of `T`, we index and recurse. Otherwise we just return `T` as-is.  If `KS` ends up being a valid path, then `DeepIdx<T, KS>` is the property there. If not, then `DeepIdx<T, KS>` is the property at the longest valid prefix in `KS`.

---

Then `ValidPathMap<T, KS>` is significantly more annoying and difficult.  In order to get the inference you want on `access()`, you want `ValidPathMap<T, KS>` to be a *homomorphic* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on `KS` (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)). That lets the compiler infer `KS` from `ValidPathMap<T, KS>`.

But the underlying implementation will probably be a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) like `DeepIdx`, so we need a wrapper for that underlying implmentation which is homomorphic:

```
type ValidPathMap<T, KS extends PropertyKey[]> = {
  [I in keyof KS]: KS extends ValidatePath<T, KS> ?
  KS[I] : I extends keyof ValidatePath<T, KS> ? ValidatePath<T, KS>[I] : never
}
```

That maps over `keyof KS` so it's homomorphic. And the underlying implementation is `ValidatePath<T, KS>`. If you analyze that you can see that `ValidatePathMap<T, KS>` will end up being just `KS` if `KS` is okay, or `ValidatePath<T, KS>` if it's not.

So we still need to implement `ValidatePath<T, KS>`. Here's one way to do it:

```
type ValidatePath<T, KS extends PropertyKey[], A extends PropertyKey[] = []> =
  KS extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
  K0 extends keyof T ?
  ValidatePath<T[K0], KR, [...A, K0]> : [...A, keyof T] : A
```

That's a [tail recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) where we accumulate (into `A`) the valid initial part of `KS`. If the whole thing is valid we end up returning `A` (which will be `KS`). If we find something invalid, we return the valid initial piece with `keyof T` replacing the first invalid part.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const res = access(obj, "nested", "deepNested");
//    ^? const res: { deepNested1: string; deepNested2: number; deepNestedArr: string[]; }
const res2 = access(obj, "nested", "nestedOther");
//    ^? const res2: string
const res3 = access(obj, "nested", "deepNested", "deepNestedArr");
//    ^? const res3: string[]
const res4 = access(obj, "nested", "deepNested", "deepNestedArr", 0);
//    ^? const res4: string
```

That stuff all works as desired, with the right types and no instantiation depth errors.  When it comes to errors and IntelliSense, it also behaves as expected:

```
access(obj, "foo"); // error!
//          ~~~~~
// Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter 
// of type '"nested" | "something" | "otherThing"'.

access(obj, "nested", "oops");
//                    ~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"oops"' is not assignable to parameter 
// of type '"deepNested" | "nestedSomething" | "nestedOther"'.(2345)
```

You can see that there are errors on the first bad key, and the error says what it expects to see.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGEQFsBTKACwEswBzALhgEYAmAZgBps5TCAnAFXKtoAiAIYQAJoLY4whaITG0sOabKjyAygWL8aMACwBWAGxTlMuWIDynLkIBmlEpPY4xhQgAcAcqvmKXym6ePhZ0QiSEADaRIM7Kge7evmIMtHoMpvFBSRYAgly2MADaIpIwgvBlgsCCALqZMAC+ps2YjQDcmJhQAJ4ehDAAIokAkmIAHgA8PCwwANLqMITjamBiEDAAClwg-Vy9c4Q9RbUAfKjsC0srhGsbRRR23PMADNer6zAA1kcgdjAzGAAOhBj2ecwASu9bp9trtuAcjidajAAPzsYaeMZTHhFOYverzCHnWg8TrdPoDABqwkiZDEwjUm0ZJGmsyuyw+Gzhe0Rx0JuWhdy2O15PUO-NQxTOFxwHJuwoeYCeXFeQthooR4qOsxBQLBqsh6u5mv22v5KPRcrenJhGx+PT+ALR7BpdIZTJZ0zxBPZENmRT1uXZBJJxSDswdTp4KNouS6vX6MDd9OZpAAssIPGz5otbcKeVqJSdzmglMURjAKN9fv8FrVaPKucnafTGYQ06zAQtzlbc0URrGYJX858o-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-xrR9giI8ju1kPth03vhp3nZd123fdXCPcQzyvYT72bSF5nAwVFiaADQlA79fNkdYYOCJDP7MIYsFdJgQA)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! You said "In order to get the inference you want on access(), you want ValidPathMap<T, KS> to be a homomorphic mapped type on KS" -> is this just common sense to you or a type checker limitation? Is there any documentation for it? I'd also love to know why my attempt was doomed. You don't seem to generate all possible tuples which I believe is costly, but should be practically ok given concrete types which are generally not that deep. My non-tail-recursive implementation doesn't help though. It is so hard to get a feel on what is a dead-end and what isn't.

Comment: TS can't infer from arbitrary types, but it can infer from some simple-ish type mappings, like homomorphic mapped types.  Your implementation generates all possible tuples, which is fine for concrete types, as you said. But inside the generic type default, the compiler doesn't know what you're doing, and it substitutes with constraints, and then it's checking something with no obvious base case. Sometimes you can get that to work, but I prefer not to try if I don't have to.