# In TypeScript, the `in` binary-operator for usage besides mapped types?

Tags: typescript

As title. I just learned that the `in` binary-operator can be used in mapped types specifically for looping through a union type from `keyof`, for example:

```
type Mappings = { ... };
type Mapped = {
  [Key in keyof Mappings]: Key
}
```

I wonder whether there is any other usage of the `in` keyword as a binary-operator in TypeScript. If so, it would be great if you could provide link(s) to the information source(s). Thank you.

Comment: "All the use cases"? There's [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (as well as [key-remapped mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)), where yes, it's used to iterate over a union type. But "use cases" is very, very, very broad, so I'm not sure how one would begin to cover *all* of them. Could you [edit] to make it much more specific what you're asking?  And could you make it clear *why* you're asking this? Are you searching by keyword or something?

Comment: @jcalz Can it be used for other expressions besides mapped types? I try to express this. Thanks for asking for editing.

Comment: *Why* do you want to know this? There's also [variance annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters) but that's a completely different thing; it's essentially a coincidence that both use "`in`". Could you please [edit] to motivate the question? Did you get a small excerpt of TypeScript that says `⋯ in Foo⋯` and you're trying to piece together what it might be from? Is this idle curiosity or is there some actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @jcalz I tried. Does it make sense now?

Comment:  "It seems that I saw this operator used in other situations but I forgot." I understand the sentence but not the motivation, sorry. This sounds more like some kind of mystery than a straightforward SO question. If I wrote an answer that said "there's mapped types and variance annotations and that's it" along with a link to documentation and a link to the compiler code where I say "look up `SyntaxKind.InKeyword` for an authoritative and exhaustive list", would that be acceptable?

Comment: It's acceptable. I don't know, that's a genuine question from my mind as a beginner trying to learn typescript. I apologize that it might sound confusing here regarding the why behind it. Sometimes I confused myself with similar syntaxes from different languages due to the lack of use and/or bad memory.

Comment: Uh, now you've updated so that it's a "binary operator"?  Okay, that's even more specific and the variance annotation doesn't even apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript isn't documented in such a way that it's indexed by *syntax*, so you can't just look up "`in`" and find a complete list of everywhere it's used in the type system. Nor does it seem particularly enlightening to do something like this, since at best, you'd be collecting essentially unrelated features whose only similarity is the use of the same bit of syntax. This question would make more sense if you had found an unexpected or novel use of `in` and were trying to understand it. But instead, you're just idly wondering if there might be other uses of `in` you haven't encountered.  It's hard to answer this authoritatively in a way that is illuminating.

Still, here goes.  You are not asking anything where `in` is compiled to JavaScript. So you don't want to know about [the JavaScript `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) or [the JavaScript `for⋯in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) or anything like that. You just want to know where it appears as a *binary operator* in the *type system*.

As you know, it appears as part of the syntax for **[mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)**, where you have `{[K in T]: U}` (or `{[K in T as P]: U}` if you're [remapping keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)).  In this case `in` is generally iterating over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members of `T`. There is a wrinkle when it comes to *homomorphic mapped types* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: U}` where you're iterating over each key in the definition of `T`, including any [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (so if `T` is `{x: 0, [k: string]: number}`, then `{[K in keyof T]: U}` will iterate over `"x"` and `string`, even though `keyof T` is just `string`.  This is all part of the mapped types feature.

After that, there don't seem to be any more places where `in` appears as a binary type operator. There is a unary `in` operator for type parameters, which, along with `out`, forms the syntax for **[optional variance annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters)** of the form `type Foo<in T> = (x: T)=>void` or `type Foo<in out T> = (x: T)=>T`.  You don't seem to be asking about this, though, and it's essentially a coincidence that `in` is used for both.

For an authoritative answer to this question, you'd need to look through [the implementation of the TypeScript type checker](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/v5.4.3/src/compiler/checker.ts), find all appearances of `SyntaxKind.InKeyword`, and figure out what it's doing. I tried to do this. Much of it was for the JavaScript `in` operator (to support things like [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)). Some of it was for mapped types, and some of it was for variance annotations. That's all I found, for the current version of TypeScript (TypeScript 5.4.3).

Comment: Thank you so much for the details :) I'm very fortunate to see this kind of high-quality answer in the era of AI.