# How to infer the array element type of each rest parameter, and create a tuple type from it?

Tags: typescript

I have taken a `zip` generator function, and I'm trying to infer the result type. Given `zip(A, B)` with A `Iterable<string>` and B `Iterable<number>` I'd want to infer the return type `Generator<[string, number][]>`

Here's what I got so far:

```
declare function zip<T extends Iterable<any>[]>(...iterables: T): Generator<T>:
```

The problem is that it infers a type union `Generator<[string[], number[]]>` instead.

The closest I think I got is something like this:

```
declare function zip<
  T extends Iterable<any>[],
  K = T extends Iterable<infer K>[] ? K : never,
>(...iterables: T): Generator<[...K[]]>
```

but that still just yields a `Generator<(string | number)[]>`, trying to infer it on the spot I just get `Generator<any[]>`:

```
declare function zip<T extends Iterable<any>[]>(
  ...iterables: T
): Generator<[...(T extends Iterable<infer K>[] ? K : never)]>
```

My desired output is:

```
declare const A: string[];
declare const B: Iterable<number>;
const z = zip(A, B);
//    ^? const z: Generator<[string, number][]>
```

Comment: Both snippets are pretty messy because I've just been shotgunning it trying to find something that works.

Comment: Can we ignore the implementation entirely? You just want a typing, right?

Comment: Yes, feel free to ignore the function body. I removed them to improve the clarity. I know you give top tier answers, and I'd really love to learn here how I can prevent losing this positional information of the rest parameter arguments, it's a problem I often run into.

Comment: So is [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE2J4N) what you're looking for? (It would be nice to have a [mre] where the test cases were already written out for us.) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to show unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: perfect! I guess I got tricked out of the correct approach by the TS error `rest parameters must be an array type`? But your `...iterables: { [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }` isn't an array type? I must say I don't know what's going on there with the interactions of `I` and `T` either. Much appreciated if you could write out an answer explaining the steps.

Comment: Is the order of the tuple guaranteed? how is it defined?

Comment: Yes, I want the type to be ordered. If the input is `f(string[], number[])` the output should be `Generator<[string, number][]>`, but if it is for example `f(number[], string[], any[])` it should be exactly `Generator<[number, string, any][]>`

Comment: It's a mapped type over an array, which yields another array (I included the link to the docs in my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use the following call signature:

```
declare function zip<T extends any[]>(
    ...iterables: { [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }
): Generator<T[]>;
```

Here the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponds to the element type of the expected *output*, so in your `zip(A, B)` example, where `A` is `Iterable<X>` and `B` is `Iterable<Y>`, then `T` would be `[X, Y]`.

Then the `iterables` rest parameter is of the [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `{ [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }`.  A mapped array/tuple turns arrays/tuples into arrays/tuples and it essentially iterates only over the numeric/numeric-like indexes of the array/tuple.  Meaning that you can think of the `I` in `keyof T` as iterating over `"0"`, `"1"`, etc., up to the largest index of the tuple.  Thus `{[I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]>}` will turn a tuple of types into a tuple of iterables of those types (e.g., `[X, Y]` becomes `[Iterable<X>, Iterable<Y>]`).  Because it's a *homomorphic mapped type* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), TypeScript is able to *infer* `T` from `{ [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }`.

Let's test it out:

```
declare const A: string[];
declare const B: Iterable<number>;
const z = zip(A, B);
//    ^? const z: Generator<[string, number][]>
```

Looks good. Given the rest input argument of type `[string[], Iterable<number>]`, the compiler is able to infer `T` as `[string, number]`, and then the output is of type `Generator<[string, number][]>`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwC8sAHAHgBV4QAPDEVYAZ3ilQE8BtAXQD4AKAFDxh8AHTisdGFABGEEIwBc8AN7wOASXhZ8AaxBscieOS7KNU2fIqbe8AL4CAlMoDi9ENIw4YN3gG4BAVBIWAQwPEYMeABBZSiYHQBzbkCQ6Dh4CNQo+AAhc0s5EFJUZABbGU8eQOzcgngAXkISPhiAGnynQIB6HpF4AD0AfiA)