Do mapped types magically detect `null` and `undefined`?
If I can trust my vscode transpiler it tells me that for each of these types the result is the one I put in comments
type keyOfNull = keyof null           // never
type keyOfundefined = keyof undefined // never
type keyOfUnknown = keyof unknown     // never
type KeyOfNever = keyof never         // string | number | symbol

However despite most of them yielding never as a type, when I pass them through a mapped type like so:
type MappedType<T> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P]}

type MappedNull = MappedType<null>           // null
type MappedUndefined = MappedType<undefined> // undefined
type MappedUnknown = MappedType<unknown>     // {}
type MappedNever = MappedType<never>         // never

The transpiler is somehow able to detect the original input even though all of the keyof type results seems the same to users: never.
(And am not even mentioning the unknown becoming {}).
So my question is:
Is this a documented behavior somewhere ? Or is this some kind of compiler wizardry deemed obvious enough to not document ?

Homomorphic mapped types (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) as implemented in ms/TS#12447 behave as the identity function for primitive types, so MappedType<string> will be string.  Essentially in keyof T is treated differently and cannot be understood as in followed by keyof T. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz it seems that this might be the point i am missing yes, please feel free to elaborate on the difference between keyof and in keyof, if you can point to an (official ?) documentation explaining this it would be an awesome bonus :)

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447 is the official documentation. TypeScript apparently moves too fast for everything to be completely documented in the handbook. They've given up entirely on having a language spec. They say "we consider the GitHub issues to be part of our official documentation". No, it's not great, but that is what it is.

@jcalz Thanks ! That's useful to know for the future
