# How can I ban keys of one interface from appearing in another interface

Tags: typescript

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is prevention of certain properties of an existing object to be passed as arguments to an interface. I believe this is possible through some combination of conditional types, but having a hard time working out the right combination.

```
export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [index: string]: T;
}

type StandardContext = {
    myKeyOne?: string;
    myKeyTwo?: number;
}

type NonStandardContext = Exclude<Dictionary<any>, StandardContext>

const standard: StandardContext = {
    myKeyOne: '2', // ok!
}

const nonStandardError: NonStandardContext = {
    myKeyOne: '2' // should error (good so far)
}

const nonStandardGood: NonStandardContext = {
    foo: '2' // should not error, but it does!
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAWACg44BtZAE1ABccAM4woyAOYBdIbQDc7AL7t2MSmDwBlGJiS8KvAMJlUIeAF5m7TpwC2lANLBKAeSTAA-ENHikEhRw29k6UtADuEF5wSACutgBGaAHKbKrqeAByZNq6%20lBGJqAWcACiINgANjH81ITEpORU1LqU9AA0cDl6BsYoRfQqbNhkoiI63flCXXkFfWZwlqyBdo7ObsBCAOQATJsdAPT7cBAA1gCESoPDSKNI2eMzJVBQ0EJZSNM9hfOL1kGrrncW12cEOIgAFhAYhVeHA0C8oHAABQSCAQWHCCBwLBQACUl1SQxG8DuHweBgA4mjeG97rkvnNiksbNi0cDNqCjsJIdDYXd4PDoB14jF4Ah4LwIMBhBc2IogA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A union between `Dictionary<any>` and `{[P in keyof StandardContext]?: never}` does it:

```
type NonStandardContext = Dictionary<any> & { [P in keyof StandardContext]?: never };
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAWACg44BtZAE1ABccAM4woyAOYBdIbQDc7AL7t2MSmDwBlGJiS8KvAMJlUIeAF5m7TpwC2lANLBKAeSTAA-ENHikEhRw29k6UtADuEF5wSACutgBGaAHKbKrqeAByZNq6+lBGJqAWBEQkZBQ0upSMAGTM3AAKiEhwANbOEOhwOXoGxihFUlHuAG5ocIoB7NhkoiI6vflCPXkFA2ZwlqyBdo7ObsBCAOQATEcANHAA9FdwEK0AhEoqbDNIc0jZC6sAolBQ0CEWSQKz6hQ2W2sQT2rncxzO11uwgAFhAYgAbXhwNAAqBwAAUEggECxwggcCwUAAlM9Uq9ZvBPiDvgYAOLE3hAr65MHrYrbGwU4nwo6IkSojFYz7wHHQS7xGLwBDwXgQYDCJ5sRRAA)

You don't need the `?` on that second part with your example `StandardContext`, but that's only because your example `StandardContext` doesn't have any required properties. If it did have some, without the `?` the type above would be impossible to satisfy since it would require you to have a property with type `never`! :-) ([Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAWACg44BtZAE1ABccAM4woyAOYBdIbQDc7AL7t2MSmDwBlGJiS8KvAMJlUIeAF5m7TpyjAAjgFcEd3kNHikEhRxsBbSgBpYEoAeSRgAH53MUkfGzgA4MpaAHcIaLgkRz8AIzQfZTZVdTwAOTJtXX0oIxNQCwIiEjIKGl1KRgAyZm4ABUQkOABrEIh0OCq9A2MUBpks4AA3NDhFH3ZsMlERHWnaoSmaurmzOEtWX1sHZ1chACJ0CAh7gBprfyCQ8OAhAHIAEx-V5wAD0oLgEGGAEIlCo2FskDskJU9scAKJQKDQIQVJBHGb1M4XD6cJLfCL-IFgiHCAAWEEcABteHA0NioHAABQSZ6s4QQOBYKAASjhxQR23gKPxaIMAHE+bjUdVCadGpcEk8IFS-jSRAzmayUfB2dAQblHPAEPBeBBgMJYWxFEA))

*(Thank you [kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299000/kaya3) for pointing out the need for `?`!)*

---

I have to admit not *fully* understanding why `Exclude<Dictionary<any>, StandardContext>` doesn't work. :-) But I think `Exclude` only works for types that don't use index signatures. **I could be wrong about why.** I suspect that from reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216010/157247) which says that `Exclude` is, roughly speaking, the following (except this is only for string keys, not string and number):

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T]
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Notice that last part excluding index keys.

Comment: I'd suggest `{ [P in keyof StandardContext]?: never }` for this, so that any properties required in `StandardContext` aren't required to exist (with values of type `never`) in `NonStandardContext`.

Comment: The OP's example doesn't have any required properties; both properties of `StandardContext` are optional, so the mapped type's properties are optional too. If `StandardContext` has any required properties, then they will be required in the mapped type too. See [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAKDnbgG1kATUALjgBnGFGQBzALqDaAbhYBfFixiUweAMoxMSHhR4BhMqhDwAvMzYcowAI4BXBDZ6CRYpOPlKVavADkyLR09KENjUHMCIhIyChodSkYAMmYuAAVEJDgAa2BKCHQ4IN19IxQI6TgkYAA3NDgFeRYAG2B4TEEApGKQsPLTOAsmOHQICEEAcgAjCgmG+SA) for an example.

Comment: @kaya3 - Thank you, I get it now!

Comment: @kaya3 - Fixed, and thank you again not only for the comment, but the explanation.