# Exclude methods from type

Tags: typescript

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48215950), but not similar enough for me to understand how to do it.

I want to copy a type, but exclude all the methods from it.

```js
interface XYZ {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z(): void;
}
```

So `z` would be excluded and I would end up with:

```js
interface XY {
  x: number;
  y: string;
}
```

I know that it's possible to do:

```js
type OmitZ = Omit<XYZ, "z">;
```

But I don't want to omit based on key string, but based on property type. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
type ExcludeFunctionKeys<T> = Pick<
  T,
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? never : K }[keyof T]
>

type XY = ExcludeFunctionKeys<XYZ>
```

Comment: Hey, I have 2 follow-up questions. I've found that this trick works nicely for optional class props, in that it makes them optional in the type too. However, that doesn't work for class props that have a default value. I would also like those to become optional in the resulting type. Is that possible? I can imagine it might not be, but I thought I'd ask anyway. And finally, I see that this trick doesn't exclude getters and setters yet. Is there a way to exclude those too?