# Function to pick all fields besides some of an object

Tags: typescript

Given the type

```
type Source = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: number,
    d: number
}
```

I would like to create a function that creates a new object from an object of type Source without some of its fields.
It should work something like this:

```
const obj1: Source = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
}

const obj2: Partial<Source> = getAllFieldsBesides(obj1, {a, c});
/*
    obj2: {
        b: 2
        d: 4
    }
*/
```

I have tried coming up with a function signature of something like this:

```
function function getAllFieldsBesides<T, K extends keyof T>(sourceObject: T, fieldsToOmit: Record<K, unknown>): Exclude<T, K>
```

But I am not sure how to go about it.

Edit: Since this was marked as a duplicate of [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type) , I would like to point that this question refers to implementing a function that can do what was described above, while the "duplicate" one only refers to creating a type that would match said requirements. Also, the linked question applies only to excluding a single known property, while mine refers to a general approach for removing any combination efficiently.

Comment: You don't need to use `Exclude` just the [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)